# Class design for serialization - ideas or patterns?

Tags: serialization, oop

Let me begin with an illustrative example (assume the implementation is in a statically typed language such as Java or C#).

Assume that you are building a content management system (CMS) or something similar. The data is hierarchically organised into `Folder`s. Each folder has a collection of children; a child may be a `Page` or a `Folder`. All items are stored within a root folder. No cycles are allowed. We have an acyclic graph.

The system will have a remote API and instances of `Folder` and `Page` must be serialized / de-serialized across the network. With a typical implementation of folder, in which a folder's children are a `List`, serialization of the root node would send the entire graph. This is unacceptable for obvious reasons.

I am interested to hear people have solved this problem in the past.

I have two potential suggestions:

1. **Navigation by query**: Change the domain model so that the folder class contains only a list of IDs for each child. To access a child we must query for it. Serialisation is now trivial since the graph ends at a well defined point. The major downside is that we lose type safety - the ID could be for something other than a folder/child.
2. **Stop and re-attach**: During serialization stop whenever we detect a reference to a folder or page, send the ID instead. When de-serializing we must then look up the corresponding object for each ID and re-attach it at the relevant position in the nascent object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of API you are trying to build, but your suggestion #1 sounds like it is close to what is recommended for REST style services and APIs. Basically, a `Folder` object would contain a list of URLs to its children.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You model the whole tree with every element being a Node, specialisations of Node being Folder and, umm, Leaf. You have a "root" Node. Nodes have a methods

```
canHaveChildren() 
getChildren()
```

Leaf nodes have the obvious behaviours (never even need to hit the network)

Folders `getChildren()` get the next set of nodes.

I did devise a system with Restful services along these lines. Seemed to be reasonably easy to program to.

Answer (score 0):

The *Navigation by query* solution was used for [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29). By reading through your question, it looks to me, as if you're trying to implements kind of a file system yourself.

If you're looking specifically into sending objects over the network there is always [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture). Aside from that there is [DCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) and the newer [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation). But wait there is more like [RMI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/rmi/index.jsp). Furthermore there are [Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). I'll stop here now.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do it by the Navigation by query method. Simply because I would like to stick with the domain model where folders contains folders or pages.

Customizing the serialization might also be tricky, bug prone and difficult to change\understand.

I would suggest that you introduce and object like `FolderBowser` in your model which takes an id and gives you a list of contents of the folder. That will make your service operations simpler.

Cheers,
Unmesh

Answer (score 0):

The classical solution is probably to use a [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), where some of the graph is sent over the network and *some* of the folders are replaced by proxies that will not have their lists of children populated until they are queried. A round trip to the server takes a significant amount of time and it will probably result in too many requests if all folders are proxies (this would yield a new request each time the contents of a folder is inspected), so you want to go for some trade off between the size of each chunk of data and the number of server requests needed in a typical scenario. This is of course application specific, but sending the contents of all child folders in for instance depth 2 might be a useful strategy...

**Long story short**: What will probably work best is your solution #1 with the exception that you want to send more than one folder at a time because of the overhead of a round trip to the server...